# How to detect open Excel files in a macro Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

How can I detect all open Excel files and run through them, in order to lock their sheets?

I have an Excel file containing the macro. Once it is launched, it would go through all my open excel files, and lock their sheets by setting a password.

Just don't know how to detect open Excel files from VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to loop on the workbooks in `Application` :

```
Dim wB as WorkBook
Dim wS as WorkSheet

For Each wB in Application.WorkBooks
    For Each wS in wB.Sheets
        wS.Protect "password"
    Next wS
Next wB
```

Comment: to set a password, I use `wS.Protect Password:="password"`

Comment: Yep! you can replace `"password"`by  `"anythingyouwant"`